# Copying columns beyond the excel 2013 limit

Tags: excel

The maximum number for columns to be displayed in Excel 2013 is 16384. Is there away to maximize this limit?

I am having a .csv dataset of 22000 columns, and when being opened with Excel 2013 it only shows till the column number 16384.

For example, I want to copy the 18000th column but I cant because it is not shown at the first place!

Any suggestions for an alternative?

Comment: Normalize your data?

Comment: Use more than one worksheet.

Comment: Transpose columns into rows. Seriously, what kind data structure has that many columns?

Comment: Copy to where?  This sounds like something that should be handled outside of Excel.

Comment: @DougGlancy I am working on an un-normalized data, wanted to compare the results with the same data but normalized version.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent it's an csv file. I can open it with any test editor, i want to view the numbers on cells cuz it would be easier working on it this way. The file does open in excel but it wont show all the columns i can see when opened with Textpad for example.

Comment: @teylyn not the right thing to do. The 22,000(attributes)should be represented as columns, while the 42(instances) should be represented as rows, before I can upload them to the data mining tool i am using.

Comment: @Byron Copy to a separate text file, that should be saved as csv, so that I can open it with microsoft excel.

Comment: So the data has 42 rows and 22,000 columns? I'd shoot the data architect. Really. It can't get any worse than that. Whatever routine extracts the data, please, please, please change it so that it transposes to deliver 22,000 rows and 42 columns. Anything else will be a head-ache.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **teylyn.**
The best way to view the data is to store each parsed record in a *column* rather than a *row.*

If we start with data like:

```
some data
a,b,v,g,t,r,12,ew,fsf,bcb,hrth,45
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a,s,d,f,g,h,765
more data
qwerty,poiuyt,asdf,zxcv,99
```

and run this short macro:

```
Sub teylyn()

    Dim TextLine As String, a
    Dim iCol As Long, iRow As Long

    Close #1

    Open "c:\TestFolder\WhatEver.csv" For Input As #1

    iCol = 1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, TextLine
        If InStr(TextLine, ",") = 0 Then
            Cells(1, iCol) = TextLine
            iCol = iCol + 1
        Else
            ary = Split(TextLine, ",")
            iRow = 1
            For Each a In ary
                Cells(iRow, iCol) = a
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Next a
            iCol = iCol + 1
        End If
    Loop

    Close #1

End Sub
```

We will get:

[image]

This is equivalent to bringing in the data in the normal way and transposing each row to a column.